# Custom text binding handler

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I created this custom binding handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.line = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        // First get the latest data that we're bound to
        var value = valueAccessor();

        // Next, whether or not the supplied model property is observable, get its current value
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);

        // Now manipulate the DOM element
        if (valueUnwrapped) {
            $(element).after('<br />');   // Make the element invisible
        }
        return ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function () {
            return valueUnwrapped;
        })
    }
};
```

I'm wondering about the part where I do `ko.bindingHandlers.text.update`.  Is there a better way to solve this?

Is it the only way to update the DOM with `ko.bindingHandler.text.update`, or is there any more straightforward way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can call it more directly using this:

```
return ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, valueAccessor);
```

The `valueAccessor` is already a function that returns the value, and `update` already uses `unwrap` internally, so there is no need to use the inline function.

Or more safely, preserving the other arguments to the handler, you can call it like this:

```
return ko.bindingHandlers.text.update.apply(this, arguments);
```

However, wrapping `text` binding handler is better done with a **preprocessor**, to ensure that other parts of the binding lifecycle are handled normally.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.line = {
    preprocess: function (value, name, addBinding) {
        addBinding('text', value);
        return value;
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        if (ko.unwrap(valueAccessor())) {
            $(element).after('<br />');   // Make the element invisible
        }
    }
};
```

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7mznw3a/).